# gawk partial cross referencing

Tags: bash, awk

So currently I have this script

```
gawk -F: '
    FNR==NR{a[$1][$2]=1;next}
    $2 in a{for(i in a[$2]) print $1 FS i}
' email.phone.txt name.email.txt
```

Example of email.phone contents:

```
Email@gmail.com:012345
Email@gmail.com:912345
```

Example of name.email.txt:

```
Charles:Email@gmail.com
Erica:Email@gmail.com
```

which will output

```
Charles:012345
Charles:912345
Erica:012345
Erica:912345
```

as you can see it currently examines 2 files and matches `email.phone.txt` first column against `name.email.txt` second column. If they match it will then output `name.email.txt` first column along with `email.phone.txt` second column using `:` as the seperator.

How can I do this to match partial strings?

Like so,

Example of email.phone contents:

```
Email@Email.com:012345
```

Example of name.email.txt:

```
Charles:Email@gm
```

expected output would now be

```
Charles:012345
Charles:912345
```

Comment: What do you mean by "partial string"? `Email@gm` is not a substring of `Email@Email.com`, nor is the other way round. Is this intended? If so, which part of the two strings is meant to be checked for matching?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to read in the **emails** and then regex-match the **telephone numbers** on the fly:

```
$ cat email.txt
Charles:Charles@gm
Erica:Erica@gmail.com

$ cat tele.txt
Charles@gmail.com:012345
Erica@gmail.com:912345
```

```
$ awk -F ':' 'NR==FNR{ em[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR{ for(i in em){
                if( $1 ~ em[i] ){ print i":"$2 } } }' email.txt tele.txt
Charles:012345
Erica:912345
```